# Java Text Measurement and Pageable getNumberOfPages()

Tags: java, printing, graphics2d

In Java Printing with `Pageable`. Lets say the exact size of the text on the pages determines the number of pages.

In the `Pageable` interface, how would you determine what value for `getNumberOfPages()` to return if we can not have a hold of `Graphics2D`?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the feeling there is no solution to this using the standard font rendering provided by Graphics2D. (Broken by design?)

Solution 1: Use another font rendering library so that text sizes are predictable.

Solution 2: Create a dummy Graphics2D from a BufferedImage using the same rendering hints between the dummy Graphics2D and the actual Graphics2D. Then hope for the best. (No guarantee of working on all systems)